# How to use the abort procedure in Chicken Scheme

Tags: scheme, abort, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to use [Chicken Scheme's](http://wiki.call-cc.org/) [abort](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Exceptions#raising-exceptions) procedure as shown in the code below:

```
(module change-calculator (export calculate-change)
  (import scheme)

  (define (calculate-change coin-values amount)
    (cond ((null? coin-values) (abort '"coin-values should contain at least one value."))
          ((= 0 amount) '() )))
)
```

but get the following warning:

```
Warning: reference to possibly unbound identifier `abort' in:
Warning:    calculate-change
```

The documentation does not mention any additional module that needs to be imported. I've tried importing `extras,utils,srfi-12` without any success. Can anyone show me the correct way to use the abort procedure? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: You don't need to put a quotation mark in front of the string here.  Strings evaluate to themselves, so quoting them does not make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, an easy mistake to make. The line `(import scheme)` should  be `(import scheme chicken)`. Good luck with your module!